Trek FX2 Random Clunking Sound
This on an eight month old Trek FX2. I live in Thailand.
Just recently this bike started making a random and loud clunking sound. It happens whether I'm pedaling or coasting. If I put it up on a rear-wheel stand and crank by hand it never makes a sound. I'm not able to pinpoint the source of the sound. I had my wife ride next to me. She could clearly hear the clunk but couldn't tell where it was coming from. Sometimes it's very loud as if someone were banging wrenches together. Sometimes it's just a quiet clunk.
Where should I look to figure this out?

What would help is to have a video where the sound is audible. Otherwise, it's common with new bikes to have screws/bolt that get a bit loose, and one of the reasons why bike shops offer a "free 300km maintenance". Some noises caused by loose bolts can be very surprising. Loose spokes can also make strange noises. So check all the bolts one the bike, and if one is loose, torque it to the recommended value. Check also so the small rings that hold the valve to the rim.

Let me try to narrow it down for you.
You have a bearing issue in a wheel. That's a WAG¹, but
You'd be amazed at the number of bikes assembled in a "Bike Shop" that are not anywhere close to ready to ride.
Pull both of your wheels off and turn the axles with your fingers. Either one clunky? (chunky, notchy, whatever term you like)
¹ Wild Assed Guess.

Check the spoke tensions. A couple may have worked loose. It doesn't happen often, but it does happen and sounds like what you describe

Thanks for the suggestions. I have an unexpected need to be away from home for a week. When I get back and if the sound is still there (see below) I'll try them out.

I realize that what follows is not a recommended maintenance procedure. But, I was out of patience so decided to dribble some ordinary motor oil into both sides of the bottom bracket. (I thought these were sealed these days?) I let the bike sit all afternoon yesterday. When I rode it this morning the sound was gone. Not a peep. Why did I think it might be the bottom bracket in spite of evidence to the contrary? My previous bike was a Trek 4300 on which I had to replace the bottom bracket five times during the eight years that I rode it. Bad luck, but that bike was jinxed from the get go.

I'm back from my trip. I did my usual cycling workout yesterday morning and there was no sound. A few hours later I went out for coffee and there were a handful of quiet clunks along the way. -- This morning I did my cycling workout with no sound at all. Later I went out for coffee and there were no sounds on the way, but as I left the coffee shop there were four loud clunks in rapid succession and then none the rest of the way home. -- The spokes are tight as are the wheel hubs. I checked everything I could see, but nothing's loose. I'm baffled.
